# Json C# multidimensional array access

Tags: c#, arrays, json, json.net

The point of the program is to find the total number of films a character has been a part of.

I'm trying to access a `Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray` type object to count the length of a multidimensional array.

#### Json array:

```
{
    "count": 1, 
    "next": null, 
    "previous": null, 
    "results": [
        {
            "name": "Luke Skywalker", 
            "height": "172", 
            "mass": "77", 
            "hair_color": "blond", 
            "skin_color": "fair", 
            "eye_color": "blue", 
            "birth_year": "19BBY", 
            "gender": "male", 
            "homeworld": "descriptiontext", 
            "films": [
                "linkapifilms1", 
                "linkapifilms2", 
                "linkapifilms3", 
                "linkapifilms6", 
                "linkapifilms7"
            ], 
            "species": [], 
            "vehicles": [
                "linapivehicles14", 
                "linapivehicles30"
            ], 
            "starships": [
                "linapistarships12", 
                "linapistarships22"
            ], 
            "created": "2014-12-09T13:50:51.644000Z", 
            "edited": "2014-12-20T21:17:56.891000Z", 
            "url": "linkapipeople1"
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm trying to access `"films":` to count the length of the array and store/display it on an int variable.

#### My Code:

```
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

public class Solution
{
    static void Main()
    {

        Console.WriteLine("Number of films: " + Run("Luke Skywalker"));
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static public int Run(string character)
    {

        int numberOfFilms = 0;
        Task<string> result = GetResponseString(character);
        var jsonResult = result.Result;

        dynamic dynamicResultObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonResult);

        JArray x = dynamicResultObject.results;
        //Find length of "films" code insert//
        Console.WriteLine(character);
        return numberOfFilms;
    }
    static public async Task<string> GetResponseString(string character)
    {

        var httpClient = new HttpClient();
        var response = await httpClient.GetAsync("linktoapi/api/people/?search=" + character);
        var contents = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        return contents;
    }
}
```

I can access the first line of array with `dynamicResultObject.results;`

#### So the question is how do I access films, which is inside results and find the length?

Edit: I understand that this may not be the best way to go about writing this program however, is it not possible to just access the child array of the main array with the current code?

Comment: `var jsonResult = result.Result;` this is a bad idea. You should be `await`ing `GetResponseString`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I parse JSON with C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6620165/how-can-i-parse-json-with-c)

Comment: I'd like to suggest you follow the procedure from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58218420/1220550) which you will give you strong typed objects that are very easy to work with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, I would advise against using `dynamic` as it will just cause you headaches.  If you're going to work with `JObjects` and `JArrays` anyway you're better off just using those types directly.  The compiler will be able to detect errors earlier and you will get the Intellisense help in Visual Studio.  So, parse your JSON like this:

```
JObject rootObject = JObject.Parse(jsonResult);
```

From that you can get your results array. (You were calling this array `x` in your code, but I think `resultsArray` is a more descriptive variable name):

```
JArray resultsArray = (JArray)rootObject["results"];
```

Like any array, if you want to get at a particular element you need to use its index.  We can get the first element of the array (which is the object containing Luke Skywalker's data) like this:

```
JObject characterObject = (JObject)resultsArray[0];
```

From there, you can get the `films` property, which is also a `JArray`:

```
JArray filmsArray = (JArray)characterObject["films"];
```

To get the length of a `JArray` you use the `Count` property:

```
numberOfFilms = filmsArray.Count;
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/iFAWB4

Now that you know how to drill down through the objects and arrays step-by-step, I'll show you a little shortcut, the `SelectToken()` method.  This method allows you to specify a "path" to get a particular `JToken` (`JObject` and `JArray` are both types of `JTokens`).  So, after parsing your JSON, you could get the `films` array directly like this:

```
JArray filmsArray = (JArray)rootObject.SelectToken("results[0].films");
```

and then get its count just like before.

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/zOdSFs

Comment: Wow thanks! Seriously appreciate the step by step breakdown of your answer, reliever of headaches.

Comment: Glad I could help!